# Redux Store cartItems is not accepting data when the addToCartHandler is called in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am in the process of creating an ecommerce website where I stumble on this problem when I try to run the addToCartHandler through a button. I have everything as I am supposed to but for some unknown reason, the cartItems I try to push data to returns undefined with the following error message `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`, which typically indicates that somewhere in your code, an attempt is made to access the push method which is state.cartItems array that is undefined.

Please help me find a possible solution with the related code below:

store/index.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import cart from "./cartSlice";

const reducers = combineReducers({ cart });
const config = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};
const reducer = persistReducer(config, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

store/index.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
};
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart(state, action) {
      console.log("Adding to cart:", action.payload);
      state.cartItems.push(action.payload);
    },
    updateCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems = action.payload;
    },
    emptyCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems = [];
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart, updateCart, emptyCart } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

pages/_app.js

```
import "@/styles/globals.scss";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import Head from "next/head";
import store from "@/store";

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Nails Republic</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="The one stop online shop for all of your manicure and pedicure needs."
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/nails_republic_icon.png" />
      </Head>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </SessionProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

productPage

```
import Rating from "@mui/material/Rating";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import { TbPlus, TbMinus } from "react-icons/tb";
import { BsHandbagFill, BsHeart } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import axios from "axios";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import { addToCart, updateCart } from "@/store/cartSlice";

export default function Infos({ product, setActiveImg }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [size, setSize] = useState(router.query.size);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState("");
  const { cart } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));
  console.log("Cart state:", cart);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSize("");
    setQty(1);
  }, [router.query.style]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (qty > product.quantity) {
      setQty(product.quantity);
    }
  }, [router.query.size]);
  const addToCartHandler = async () => {
    if (!router.query.size) {
      setError("Please Select a size");
      return;
    }
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/product/${product._id}?style=${product.style}&size=${router.query.size}`
    );
    if (qty > data.quantity) {
      setError(
        "The selected quantity is more than in stock. Try and lower the Qty"
      );
    } else if (data.quantity < 1) {
      setError("This Product is out of stock.");
      return;
    } else {
      let _uid = `${data._id}_${product.style}_${router.query.size}`;
      dispatch(
        addToCart({
        ...data,
        qty,
        size: data.size,
        _uid,
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.infos}>
      <div className={styles.infos__container}>
        <h1 className={styles.infos__name}>{product.name}</h1>
        <h2 className={styles.infos__sku}>{product.sku}</h2>
        <div className={styles.infos__rating}>
          <Rating
            name="half-rating-read"
            defaultValue={product.rating}
            precision={0.5}
            readOnly
            style={{ color: "#5a141d" }}
          />
          ({product.numReviews}
          {product.numReviews == 1 ? " review" : " reviews"})
        </div>
        <div className={styles.infos__price}>
          {!size ? <h2>{product.priceRange}</h2> : <h1>{product.price}₦</h1>}
          {product.discount > 0 ? (
            <h3>
              {size && <span>{product.priceBefore}₦</span>}{" "}
              <span>(-{product.discount}%)</span>
            </h3>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
        <span className={styles.infos__shipping}>
          {product.shipping
            ? `+${product.shipping}$ Shipping fee`
            : "Free Shipping"}
        </span>
        <span>
          {size
            ? product.quantity
            : product.sizes.reduce((start, next) => start + next.qty, 0)}{" "}
          pcs left.
        </span>
        <div className={styles.infos__sizes}>
          <h4>Select a Size : </h4>
          <div className={styles.infos__sizes_wrap}>
            {product.sizes.map((size, i) => (
              <Link
                href={`/product/${product.slug}?style=${router.query.style}&size=${i}`}
              >
                <div
                  className={`${styles.infos__sizes_size} ${
                    i == router.query.size && styles.active_size
                  }`}
                  onClick={() => setSize(size.size)}
                >
                  {size.size}
                </div>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.infos__colors}>
          {product.colors &&
            product.colors.map((color, i) => (
              <span
                className={i == router.query.style ? styles.active_color : ""}
                onMouseOver={() =>
                  setActiveImg(product.subProducts[i].images[0].url)
                }
                onMouseLeave={() => setActiveImg("")}
              >
                <Link href={`/product/${product.slug}?style=${i}`}>
                  <img src={color.image} alt="" />
                </Link>
              </span>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.infos__qty}>
          <button onClick={() => qty > 1 && setQty((prev) => prev - 1)}>
            <TbMinus />
          </button>
          <span>{qty}</span>
          <button
            onClick={() => qty < product.quantity && setQty((prev) => prev + 1)}
          >
            <TbPlus />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.infos__actions}>
          <button
            disabled={product.quantity < 1}
            style={{ cursor: `${product.quantity < 1 ? "not-allowed" : ""}` }}
            onClick={() => addToCartHandler()}
          >
            <BsHandbagFill />
            <b>ADD TO CART</b>
          </button>
        </div>
        {error && <span className={styles.error}>{error}</span>}
        {success && <span className={styles.success}>{success}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Inside the `slice` file, you're exporting `cartSlice.reducer` but the property is actually called `reducers` with an `s`. Is that a typo?

Comment: You don't need to shallow copy state in the selector function, change `const { cart } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));` to `const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);`.

Comment: @SamR. No, there's no typo there, you define individual reducer cases, the slice exports a single reducer. [`reducers`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#reducers) is the property in the slice configuration object, `reducer` is the [returned property](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#return-value) that is the "combined" reducer function.